# TimeStamp issue in oracle 11

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp

I've a table in oracle and I'm trying to load a .CSV file to it.

Here is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE Table_test 
   (    
    ID VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),     
    Code VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),     
    XST_TYM TIMESTAMP (6),     
    PRD_TYM TIMESTAMP (6),     
    Code_done VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)    
   )
```

Here are the timeStamps I'm trying to insert through the file.

**01:19.0**

**11:12.0**

I'm getting an error **"java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month"**

Comment: thw way I understand TIMESTAMP , it contains date and time both.

Comment: A `TIMESTAMP` contains a day and a time.  Oracle does not have a `time` data type.  You may want to use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND(6)` if you are trying to store intervals.  Or you may want to store the time as a `VARCHAR2` (though that would make manipulating the time cumbersome if you wanted to subtract one from the other to get an interval.

Comment: NEVER store date or time values as string. It generates always problems.

Comment: @Wernfried - It doesn't make sense to store a date as a `varchar2` because there is a proper `date` data type.  If you really need to store the time rather than an interval, it may make sense to use a `varchar2` because there is no `time` data type assuming that you aren't doing calculations based on the time that was stored.  It may make sense to use a `date` where the day is always set to some fixed value but that creates its own set of problems.

Comment: @JustinCave: I don't agree with you. If you really need only a time without any date information I would rather prefer to use a number instead, i.e. number of hours/minutes/seconds (depends on your need) from midnight.